# Amber paramfit "monomer (or ligand)" problem

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

I am trying to parameterize a novel molecule which has atoms not included gaff or parm force field. I finished parameterizing vdw-bond and angle force field. Also I did PES Scan for dihedrals and I wrote them in a frcmod file as truncated fourrier integral. Yes, actually most probably I will not need paramfit parameterization but I wondered and I tested paramfit.

Here is tutorial:
http://ambermd.org/tutorials/advanced/tutorial23/index.html#Introduction

I succesfully finished this tutorial and after this I tried to apply paramfit to my "monomer" and "not included any force field" molecule. But xleap gives some error message and I locked completely. 
I changed [gen_conformers.sh](http://ambermd.org/tutorials/advanced/tutorial23/files/gen_conformers.sh) (Don't click if you don't want to download!) for my molecule and I couldn't obtain different conformations.

Then I tested where was the mistake. I created leapin file like this:

```
source oldff/leaprc.ff99
addAtomTypes { { "B" "B" "sp3" } }
addAtomTypes { { "O" "O" "sp3" } }
addAtomTypes { { "C" "C" "sp3" } }
a=loadmol2 bor.mol2
loadamberparams bor.dat
impose a {1 1}, { {"H1" "O2" "B3" "O4" 72.000} }
impose a {1 1}, { {"O12" "B3" "O4" "C5" 19.000} }
impose a {1 1}, { {"B3" "O4" "C5" "C6" 108.000} }
impose a {1 1}, { {"B3" "O12" "C13" "H18" 11.000} }
saveamberparm a a_1.prmtop a_1.mdcrd
check a
quit
```

then I run this file with this command:

```
xleap -f leapin
```

but after that leap.log file:

```
  Checking Unit.
Building topology.
Building atom parameters.
Building bond parameters.
Building angle parameters.
Building proper torsion parameters.
Building improper torsion parameters.
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C2 H5 C1 H6
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C1 H2 C2 H3
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C1 H2 C2 H4
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C1 H3 C2 H4
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  H-H-C-H
        atoms are: H2 H3 C2 H4
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C4 H10 C3 H11
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C3 H7 C4 H8
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C3 H7 C4 H9
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  C-H-C-H
        atoms are: C3 H8 C4 H9
 ** Warning: No sp2 improper torsion term for  H-H-C-H
        atoms are: H7 H8 C4 H9
 total 7 improper torsions applied
```

and after that, even if I changed angles many many times in "impose" command

```
 impose a {1 1}, { {"B3" "O4" "C5" "C6" 108.000} }
```

I obtained the same *.inpcrd files and I couldn't generate different conformation gaussian job file.
So how can I apply paramfit for a ligand? (or monomer)

Comment: amber has a mailing list, you may have better luck on that.

http://lists.ambermd.org/mailman/listinfo/amber

Comment: What is "monomer or ligand" ? We're not a helpdesk here, questions should make sense to other people, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about how to use AMBER.

Comment: I think opposite. The question is about applying genetic algorithm (G.A) to dihedrals. And paramfit is the only software can do this.( Why I am saying this? here: https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.23775 ) So even if user don't want to talk about paramfit he/she has to talk about paramfit. Another problem that the user faces is not to be able to save the related coordinate files by turning the dihedral angles.(xleap)
Charmm, tinder, gromacs softwares are already using "amber ff " so in this respect, all molecular simulations have to do with "amber" thus problem is  more complex than it looks.

Comment: Erdem, I think I found answer, ( Iwas facing with the same problem for about 1 month) I tested for my molecule and I got true results: to obtain rand conformers; Instead of xleap use another program and skip this step of the paramfit tutorial with these conformers (you will need to change *.dat files according to your dihedral angels, this is fatal important). You can use this program:  
http://en.freedownloadmanager.org/Windows-PC/ArgusLab-FREE.html
Good Luck!